# with-constrained consecutive updates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Please assume I have built a query in MS Sqlserver, it has the following structure:

```
WITH issues_a AS
(
  SELECT a_prop
  FROM ds_X x
)
, issues_b AS
(
  SELECT key
       , z.is_flagged as is_flagged
       , some_prop
  FROM ds_Z z
    JOIN issues_a i_a
      ON z.a_diff = i_a.a_prop
)
-- {{ run }}
UPDATE samples
  SET error =
    CASE
      WHEN i_b.some_prop IS NULL THEN '#1 ...'
      WHEN UPPER(i_b.is_flagged) != 'Y' THEN '#2 ...'
    END
FROM samples s
  left join issues_b i_b ON s.key = i_b.key;
```

Now I want enhance the whole thing, updating one more table in a consecutive way by enclosing parts of the query in `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`, but don't get my head around the how of it. Tried enclosing the whole expression with the transaction parenthesis, but that didn't bring me any further.

Are there any other ways to achieve the above task - even without concatenating the consecutive updates in a transactional manner, though better it would be?

For abbreviation the task again: `WITH <...>(...), <...>(...) UPDATE <... Using data from latter WITH> UPDATE <... using data from latter WITH>`?

Hope you don't mind my poor grammar...

Comment: You can only have one update target. For two targets you must have two different updates, each with its own set of `with`s, even if they are identical.

Comment: Why use a CTE for SELECT a_prop FROM ds_X x?  Just join directly on the table.